# Solving this momentum operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics, differential-operators

I would appreciate some help in understanding what how this operator is being multiplied in the following equation:

$$x_{op}p^2_{op,x}=\left(p_{op,x}x_{op}+i\hbar\right)p_{op,x}$$

(basically how to solve LHS to get RHS)

From the looks of it somehow there is a derivation applied to both $x$ and $p$ operator but I can't understand why as $x$ is before $p$ to start with and so the $d/dx$ in $p$ won't be applicable to $x$!?

In case you need the full solution it is from, it can be seen below[image: solution]

Many thanks!

Comment: These are linear transformations, you read them right to left. For instance, $ABx=A(Bx)$ so $A$ acts on $B$ - not the other way around.

Comment: I know that but the solution above seems to be doing something that I can't seem to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x_{op}p_{op,x}^2=x_{op}p_{op,x}p_{op,x}=(x_{op}p_{op,x})p_{op,x}$$
We know that $$[x_{op},p_{op,x}]=x_{op}p_{op,x}-p_{op,x}x_{op}=i\hbar$$
so we can move the second term on the other side
$$x_{op}p_{op,x}=i\hbar+p_{op,x}x_{op}$$
Finally, we plug this result in the first equation, and you get your desired result